# Node Js Checking if user email is already exits

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

Hi New Here and learning node js with express i want a way to check if the user email is
already exits in database i am trying to do this like this

```
const emailExits = user.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if(emailExits) return res.status(400).send('Email already exits');
```

but every time i type any email that is not in database just tell email already exit how ever
the email is never stored in database

if you have any good way to do this please tell what is wrong

Comment: `user.findOne(...)` returns a Promise. A Promise is truthy, so your `if` is always executed. You either need to `await` that Promise (`const emailExists = await user...`), or use callbacks

Comment: thanks  @blex it worked i have to use await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.findOne()` is asynchronouse, you need to put an `.then()` at the end, use a callback or use `async / await`

```
try {
   const emailExits = await user.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
   if(emailExits) return res.status(400).send('Email already exits');
}catch(err){
console.log(err);
}
```

Dont forget to put `async` infront of your handler function

Answer (score 0):

user.findOne(...) is an asynchronous operation, your code tries to access emailExist variable before the value is assigned to it, thus returning undefined. There are few ways to handle async code, i.e.

```
return user.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
  .then(email => {
    if(user) return res.status(400).send('Email already exits');

    //do something if user does not exist
    return ...
  })
  .catch(err=> new Error(err))
```

Keep in mind you need to return each value though